# Manipular texto XML para exibir ao usuário com javascript vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Olá, tenho um text área que o user irá inserir o texto XML colado, para cadastro de uma API. e após isso preciso renderizar para o user o xml formatado com os campos. existe alguma lib que ajude nessa tarefa? ou um jeito simples de fazê-la?

Comment: Leia https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Parsing_and_serializing_XML

Comment: Obrigado Augusto!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) para fazer a interepretação do XML.
Já que estás a utilizar vuejs, podes fazer *binding* do campo com `v-model` e depois executar uma função nos `methods` para fazer a interpretação.

Exemplo:

```html
<div id="app">
  <textarea v-model="xml"></textarea>
  <button @click="parse">Parse</button>
</div>

<script>
  const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      xml: "",
    },
    methods: {
      parse() {
        let parser = new DOMParser();
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(this.xml, 'text/xml');

        // Ler valores do XML
        let val1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("nome_do_campo_val1")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Podes ver mais uns exemplos [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou